# Is it improper to use the Right Quote character, if there's no Left Quote character paired with it?

Tags: orthography, typography, quotation-marks, measuring-units

Laying out a printed catalog (for distribution in the United States), I'm listing the dimensions (using inches) for numerous products.

I like Proxima Nova's Right Quote character more than the generic Quote character because I think it's more recognizable at smaller sizes.

[image: Screenshot of Indesign CC 2014, showing Proxima Nova open in the glyphs panel.]

But . . . might this be considered technically wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typography, not English Language Usage.

Comment: A tricky grey area. I was unsure.
Though I suspect my question relates more to accurate communication via use of language, and not so much just a typogaphical/font issue.

Comment: A grey area, I agree.  I wasn't sure if it would be better answered on another SE site but couldn't really determine which site.  In my catalog copywriter days our text was handled by a typesetter so I'm no help to you - sorry!

Comment: The short answer is yes, it's *technically* wrong. Most people probably won't notice. But those who do notice will notice instantly, and will judge your typography skills accordingly.

Comment: @choster: OP's context is a rare one where a "dumb" quote should be used rather than a “smart” one. Since it normally takes more effort to use the latter, I'd assume anyone who did it had limited typography skills. In the more normal case (either using or failing to use “smart” quotes) I infer nothing whatsoever. But in the case of double/single prime marks (as per your answer), I infer you must be a typesetter in your spare time! (either that or "choster" is an alias for "tchrist", who also specializes in obscure typographic details! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I learned a lot more about the proper use of broken bars, dieses, interpuncts, and the lot working in web design than I ever did in school, the prescriptiveness being very thinly veiled in appeals to accessibility (what would a screen reader say if you used a masculine ordinal indicator (º) instead of a degree symbol (°)? Horror upon horrors). At least I didn't mention that the dimensions seem to be separated by a lowercase letter *x* instead of the proper multiplication sign (×).

Comment: A reasonable approximation of a double prime in many fonts that lack the real thing is a standard double quote in italic/oblique.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone!
choster, I replaced all lowercase x's with the legitimate multiplication glyph. Over 550 replacements made, document-wide. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inches (like [seconds of arc](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArcSecond.html) and [seconds of time](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27150)) are denoted by the *[double prime mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol))*, **not** a quotation mark, although for ease of typing, it is common to see the straight quotation mark (the "[dumb quote](http://smartquotesforsmartpeople.com/)" found on most computer keyboards) used in its place.

The most typographically correct presentation would be

> ### 4⅝ × 3¾″

and *not*

> ∅ 4⅝ × 3¾"

but definitely not

> ∅ 4⅝ × 3¾”

The double prime character is Unicode point U+2033.